# Не работает атрибут "android:imeOptions"

Tags: android, android-edittext, клавиатура

В некотором `layout` есть `EditText` и если  по [документации](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions) от Google установить этому виджету атрибут `android:imeOptions="actionSearch"`, то вместо стандартного значка "Enter" на клавиатуре должна появиться иконка поиска (лупа).  Но когда я попробовал это реализовать на практике

```
        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"/>
```

иконка осталась прежней. Т.е смена иконки не работает. 
Попробовал реализовать смену иконки программно, написав в `Activity` : `editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH);` Это, к сожалению, тоже не сработало. Более того, видимо как следствие этого, не работает и переопределенный метод для обработки нажатия по кнопке поиска:

```
    @Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {

    Log.d("WHALETAG", "Что то собирается нажаться");
    if (i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Поиск: " + editText.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

От чего такое?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение нашлось довольно нестандартно:

если это происходит, необходимо для `EditText` указать еще один атрибут `android:singleLine="true"`

И в результате получится:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:singleLine="true"/>
```

и иконка поиска будет исправно отображаться.